# How do I add if on excel to another if formula

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, formulas

I'm trying to add a formula to an existing formula.  Pretty much right now we have a 5 point scale but I need to add an if by department.

Pretty much the current formula is: =IF(b16<>"",Vlookup(b16,scales!q26:r30,2,1),"")

I'm about to add new scales based on departments, so the department will be on cell B8.  I need a formula to say for example, IF B8 equals dispatch, use this Scale, if equals care use this scale, etc.

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Without providing sample data and what kind of output you are trying to achieve, nobody will be able to answer your question without guessing.

Comment: `=If($B$8="dispatch",[formula],If($B$8="care",[other formula],""),"")`??